# getting different value from source code in the main function in c

Tags: c

i am trying to understand how to link different files work using this small code

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "try.h"

void main()
{
    printf("%i",a);
}
```

in try.h

```
#include "stdint.h"
uint64_t a ;
```

in try.c

```
#include "try.h"
uint64_t a=1;
```

the result is 0 which is mentioned otherwise in try.c
i can not seem to understand , is this a compiler or linker error .
how i get the main function to print 1

Answer (score 3):

It actually shows that the linking is not successful. If you try to link with try.c, it will break.

When you included try.h, the compiler basically copies its content:

```c
#include "stdint.h"
uint64_t a ;

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "try.h"

void main()
{
    printf("%i",a);
}
```

Note that there's nothing related to "try.c" at this point. If you run it, then `a` is not initialised and it happens to be 0 (because un-initialized file-scope variable will be allocated to .bss with 0 value).

If you decided to link with "try.c", an error will occur since `a` is defined twice. Therefore there are two things that need to be fixed:

1. In try.h, change it to `extern uint64_t a;` this means you promised that `a` will be defined somewhere, but not in the header.
2. Link it properly. We'll be able to help more on this if you tell us how are you attempting to link it currently.

Comment: i am using code blocks , so i assume it links the files together once i copied it in the main directory

Comment: dont assume. make sure it does link properly.

Comment: I am not familiar with this IDE, thus I cannot give any advice regarding it; I only know how to link it manually in command line or use a Makefile. Based on your question it seems there's no linking happening.

Comment: If you created a project and added each of the files to the project, CodeBlocks will compile and link it all. Better, add the `/path/to/MinGW/bin` to your user path and then open the command prompt and build there, e.g. `gcc -Wall -Wextra -O2 -std=C11 -o main main.c try.c` and that will produce `main.exe` which you can run.